# Dependency Injection asp.net core without constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have written a class like below

```
public sealed class SomeAttribute : Attribute, IResultFilter
{ 
   private INotificationhub notificationHub;
   public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContect filterContext)
   {

     //Need to set value notificationHub by resolving dependency

    //some other logic here


   }

}
```

in ConfigureServices of asp.net core

I have written

```
services.AddSingleton<INotificationHub, NotificationHub>();
```

How can I resolve the dependecy in the attribute class. I cannot  do a constructor injection.

Comment: This link may be of use, to demonstrate how to inject dependencies action filters. A similar use case as yours. 

https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following work for you:

```
public sealed class SomeAttribute : Attribute, IResultFilter
{ 
   private INotificationhub notificationHub;
   public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContect filterContext)
   {

     //Need to set value notificationHub by resolving dependency
    notificationHub = filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<INotificationhub>();

        // …
    //some other logic here


   }

}
```

Excellent article here, explaining this and other options: https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core

Comment: Where is the article?I will try out the code provided by you and let you know

Comment: Sorry missed it during edit.